# Parameter error in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, parameters, mysql-error-1064, ddl, procedure

This code shows syntax error in the parameter declaration.. Pls help me to solve

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ADDCOURSE`(@Course varchar(45),@Branch varchar(45),@Batch INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE I INT;
    SET I=1;
    LABEL1: LOOP
        INSERT INTO course 
        (Course, Branch, Batch)
         VALUES(@Course, @Branch, I);
        IF I <= @Batch THEN
            SET I=I+1;
            ITERATE LABEL1;
        END IF;
        LEAVE LABEL1;
     END LOOP LABEL1;
END
```

Comment: Don't use `@` in the parameter names in the header line. just `Course`, `Branch`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

`DELIMITER $$`

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE ADDCOURSE(
    Course varchar(45), Branch varchar(45), Batch INT
)

BEGIN
    DECLARE I INT;
    SET I = 1;
    LABEL1: LOOP
        INSERT INTO course 
        (Course, Branch, Batch)
         VALUES(@Course, @Branch, I);
        IF I <= @Batch THEN
            SET I=I+1;
            ITERATE LABEL1;
        END IF;
        LEAVE LABEL1;
    END LOOP LABEL1;
END

$$
```

Comment: As Marc B suggested... I just removed the @ because it didn't seem that there were any variables defined.